# missing token ‘****’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel, IONIC2 with meteor CLI

Tags: ionic2, angular-meteor

I am new to meteor+ionic2, I am trying to make an app where I need to make an http call and pass some parameters in headers, It is giving the error **missing token ‘language’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel,**
I tried providing proxies in ionic.config.json and even whitelisting url in mobile-config.js, but none of them helps, please help.

**Note: It works when I use plugin to allow CORS in Chrome**

Comment: Can you show the request with headers and response with headers?

Comment: `this.allNewsObj = this.httpClient.get(this.BASE_URL + '/generic/api/language', {
            headers: {
                "news_language": this.language,
                "newsclientuniqid": this.uniqueId
            }
        });` This the request with header @misha130

Comment: No, no the chrome request/response with the headers. What do you see in the actual browser

Comment: Failed to load http://url.to.api:8080/NewsAppBeta/generic/api/language: Request header field news_language is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
:
"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
"Unknown Error"
url
:
null

Comment: @misha130 I migrated my project from Meteor CLI to Ionic CLI and proxies worked for me